# MiKTeX missing latex.exe file

Tags: lyx, miktex

After downloading and installing MiKTeX, I went on to download LyX.

[image]

I was then prompted to choose the path for my LaTeX distribution. I chose the path to where my MiKTeX is supposed to store its latex.exe file, but I get the error message "The file latex.exe is not in the specified path."

After checking the path, I couldn't find latex.exe.
I've uninstalled and installed LyX and MiKTeX several times in the past few hours, but nothing works.

I've gone through all the steps (which aren't too complicated) and it's becoming absurd!

Comment: latex.exe is only a rather small wrapper, miktex normally creates it when making the formats the first time. Go to the miktex console (admin mode), to the settings, tab formats, check if latex is included and trigger the creation of the latex format. If this fails you can also try on a command line (with admin rights)  `initexmf --admin --mklinks`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see 'latex' in the formats tab. I pressed 'Build format' and it seemed to do something. 
I then went on to try and download LyX again, and yet again it fails with the message "The file latex.exe is not in the specified path."

Comment: MiKTeX is an odd beast it does not always install where LyX correctly expects it to. at a command prompt run/check **`where /r c:\ latex`** more importantly check `where $path:latex` gives LyX exactly the same information not a "unknown" location

Comment: Check if miktex is working before fighting with lyx.

Comment: Thanks people! What solved it eventually was downloading the *portable version* of MiKTeX.

Comment: In my case, when checking for updates from the miktex console, the latex.exe file was created.